# Splitting data into dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a long list values like below and am thinking of converting this to a dictionary. I would like to create dictionaries in python where for each key 0, 1, 2,...(say n), the value is sum of all values that belong to that key. For example,

```
0 -29.8568331501
1 -27.4866699437
2 -27.1228643508
0 -10.8685684486
1 -9.41353774283
2 -10.3218886291
...
```

Then,

```
dict = {0: SUM(-29.8568331501+-10.8685684486+..), 1:SUM(-27.4866699437+-9.41353774283+..), 2:1:SUM(-27.1228643508+-10.3218886291+..)}
```

I am a python newbie and would appreciate any guidance on how to go about doing this.

Comment: is the data in a file?

Comment: no, I am generating this data computationally and am not reading it from a file

Comment: that data looks unlike any format I have seen before, what exactly is it stored in?

Comment: it's not stored, this is a result of doing computation within a def function that I have written in a loop which is generating sequence like 0,1,2,0,1,2,01,2....

Answer (score 2):

So assuming you have the data read into a list already (or are using a generator) you can indeed do this in a very simple way:

```
from collections import defaultdict

sums = defaultdict(float)
for key, val in data:
    sums[key] += val
```

I advise you to familiarize yourself with the `collections` module, because it has a lot of *right tools* for many jobs. In this case `defaultdict` is just like a normal python dictionary but it has a default value for keys that are not yet in it (in this case the default value is the value of `float()` which is `0.0`). Thanks to this, you do not need to bother with checking if the key already exists in the dict.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, two things:

1. if your keys are actually 1...N, then don't use a dictionary but a simple list.
2. solution with a dict, that I, for clarity, called `dictionary`. The 1...N are the `key`s, and your floating point numbers are the `value`s:

   if key is in dictionary:
        dictionary[key] += value else:
        dictionary[key] = value

You need to apply that to each `key, value` pair.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension as outlined in:

[Mapping Over Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229064/mapping-over-values-in-a-python-dictionary)

```
tmpDict = {k: f(k,v) for k, v in tmp.items()}
```

Replacing `f(k,v)` with a function that performs the sums.

*Example:*

Generate data

```
tmp = {}

for i in range(0, 10):
    tmp [i] = [i for x in range(0, 10)]
```

> {0: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 1: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 2: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 3: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 4: [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], 5: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], 6: [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6], 7: [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], 8: [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8], 9: [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]}

Perform bucketed sum(s)

```
tmpDict = {k: sum(v) for k, v in tmp.items()}
```

**Result Set:**

> {0: 0, 1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50, 6: 60, 7: 70, 8: 80, 9: 90}

Comment: How does this help? `tmp` would have to be a dict (of what?) and the function `f` would need to have global state to keep track of the sums, which effectively removes the need for the dictionary comprehension. It seem like 1 problem has been replaced by 3.

Comment: @jepio the function `f` was intended to be a placeholder for the `sum` operation.

Comment: I agree that if you have the data in the same format as your `tmp` dictionary, than a dict comprehension with sum is the easiest solution. But first you need to translate the data to this format. For the data in the question I came up with the following:
`data.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0));
b = {k: sum(v for _, v in vals) for k, vals in itertools.groupby(data, itemgetter(0))}`
I would not say this is a particularly easy solution...

Comment: That's a fair assessment; stored as a dictionary that the dict comprehension is the way to go. I don't see how else you store the aforementioned data. (e.g.) `{1:1,1:2,1:3}` yields `{1:3}` -- I'll ask the OP.