# Python: syntax to update a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, operators

Here we update a dictionary:

```
child = {'i':0, 'name': 'Mike', 'age': 5, 'weight': 17}
child.update({'age': x['age']+1, 'weight': 20})
```

Any way to use an operator like age += 1 or more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Hmm... can you elaborate on what is `x` and how does it fit in with your question?

Comment: uh. `child['age'] += 1` works if that's what you meant.

Comment: Relevant, though not a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229064/mapping-over-values-in-a-python-dictionary

Comment: Replace `x` with `child`, and the code would work, though it's still not terribly elegant.

Comment: A method like `update_map` might be nice: `child.update_map({'age': lambda x=0: x + 1, 'weight': lambda x: 20)`. Each value in the update dict is not the new value for the key, but a function to compute the new value from the old. For new keys, a default default value of `None` could be supplied to the function. Here, the `age` function will use `0` as the old age if the key isn't present, while the `weight` function would receive `None` (and ignore it).

Comment: Sorry, x should be child. chepner nailed it. Update_map would have been the solution I kind of had in my mind but overall it's a little bit overengineered. child['age'] += 1 does the job and is perfectly readable and compact.

Answer (score 2):

Just do `child['age']+=1`:

```
>>> child = {'i':0, 'name': 'Mike', 'age': 5, 'weight': 17}
>>> child
{'i': 0, 'age': 5, 'name': 'Mike', 'weight': 17}
>>> child['age']+=1
>>> child
{'i': 0, 'age': 6, 'name': 'Mike', 'weight': 17}
```

Comment: I think the goal is to update `age` and `weight` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

if the dictionary already has the item with a given key you can update it using the key and new data like this:

```
child['age'] +=1
child['weight'] = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [multiple assignment](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-variables-in-python-3#multiple-assignment) A simple feature in python that we tend to forget about.

```
child['age'], child['weight'] = child['age'] + 1, 20
print(child)
```

Output:

> {'i': 0, 'name': 'Mike', 'age': 6, 'weight': 20}