# How to map model data(query set) into dictionary and use it as ordered list

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-models, django-queryset

[Mapping over values in a python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229064/mapping-over-values-in-a-python-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you post a example or code, it will be more clear, but i think that your are needding something like that: 
For example if your model is called Data

```
values=Data.objects.value().order_by('field_name') # make a query and order data
list=[value for value in values ]   # storage data as a list of dictionaries
```

I hope that this help you